# com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget is closed source?

Tags: android

I wanted to check something in the source code of com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget , but I can't find it anywhere. Is it closed source?

Comment: Uhm, maybe this question belongs to android stack exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it closed source?

Yes, it is.